# Dart: parse api response and dynamically create child T from parent

Tags: flutter, dart

Looking for a clean way to parse out data from an API.

The API returns data for creating “Boat” and “Car” models wrapped up in metadata.

```
{
    “timestamp” “0000”,
    “data”: {
        “count” “1”,
        “results” [
            {
                “name”: “boatyMcBoatFace”
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to create 2 classes for the metadata and also the boat/car data using custom `fromJson()` methods.
Current implementation is something like this

```
Class Boat {
    String name;
    
    Boat.fromJson(json) {
        this.name = json[‘name’]
    }
    static List<Boat> listFromJson(List<dynamic> json) {
        return json.map((c) => Boat.fromJson(c)).toList();
    }
}

ResponseModel<T> {
    String timestamp
    DataModel data
    
    ResponseModel.fromJson(json) {
        this.timestamp = json[‘timestamp’]
        this.data = DataModel<T>.fromJson(json[‘data’])
    }
}

DataModel<T> {
    String count
    List<T> results 
    
    DataModel.fromJson(json) {
        this.count = json[‘count’]
        this.results = json[‘results’] // change this, see below
    }
}
```

Currently I'm creating a ResponseModel, which in turn creates a DataModel.
But then I'm manually creating and setting Boats using:

```
// yes
final res = methodThatMakesHttpRequest();
final apiResponse = ResponseModel<Boat>.fromJson(res);

// no
final boats = Boat.listFromJson(apiResponse.data.results);
apiResponse.data.results = boats;
```

Ideally I would remove those last two lines, and instead have Boats get created dynamically within `DataModel.fromJson` with something like

```
    DataModel.fromJson(json) {
        this.count = json[‘count’]
        T.listFromJson(json[‘results’])
    }
```

But this of course does not work as T.listFromJson does not exist.